# android.widget.HoverPopupWindow cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I recently followed a tutorial over on XDA to repackage the default android.jar to allow access to internal and hidden APIs. I pulled the messaging app from my phone which is running the Eclipse S4 TW ROM. I want to add direct call functionality to the app as it currently does not support it. I decompiled the app with apk-tool and converted the dex files to java source files using dex2jar and then JD-GUI. The problem is when in Eclipse I get an error saying "The type android.widget.HoverPopupWindow cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" I am currently using the android-17 API and cannot find anything in reference to a HoverPopupWindow. Could this be a result of the repackaging of android.jar? Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was digging around some more and stumbled upon a file in the /system/framework directory called framework2.jar. After decompiling the file and extracting the classes I found a java class called android.widget.HoverPopupWindow. I added that file to my package and resolved the error.